# How can users share entities if they have a relation?

Tags: entities

Im setting up a pretty complicated website, where users are going to have access to a certain nodes depending on which entities the user of the relation has.

with profile 2, i did add an entity reference field, which displays the nodes im going to grant / restrict permissions on the profile registration.

Its going to be something like this:

Me (admin) is going to create a SUB ADMIN user, i set which nodes is he / she going to be able to access.

The SUB ADMIN user, creates users with the role of normal users. The user itself is going to have less privileges than the SUB ADMIN user, and is going to have the same restrictions on the nodes than the SUB ADMIN user.

... i know its a bit complicated, but i would love to know if there's any way to share the entities of the SUB ADMIN user to the user he creates?.

Using this modules right now:
ENTITIES REFERENCE
PROFILE 2
RELATION
SUB USER

Hope you guys could help me... Thanks in advance!.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know about [Node Access Relation](https://drupal.org/project/node_access_relation), it sounds like maybe you want to use it.

> - You use or plan on using the Relation module and want to grant users
>     access to view/edit/delete content based on their relations.
> - You find
>     Drupal roles too broad but per-node access controls too much to manage